# How to create Bean in SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, javabeans

I have a `MongoUserUrlRepository` from which I have to create Bean.

Code looks like this:

```java
public class MongoUserUrlRepository extends AbstractRepositoryImpl<MongoUserId, UserUrl> implements UserUrlRepository {

    public MongoUserUrlRepository(MongoClient mongoClient, String db, String collection) {
        super(
                mongoClient,
                db,
                collection,
                MongoUserId::asString,
                id -> MongoUserId.mongoUserId((String) id)
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected Document toDocument(UserUrl uv) {
        final Document d = new Document();

        uv.url.ifPresent(url -> d.put("url",url));
        d.put("version", uv.version);
        d.put("requestedDate", toDate(uv.requestedDate));
        d.put("state", uv.state.name());
        return d;
    }

    @Override
    protected UserUrl fromDocument(Document d) {
        return UserUrl.userUrl(
                idFrom(d),
                d.getString("url"),
                d.getLong("version"),
                toInstant(d.getDate("requestedDate")),
                State.valueOf(d.getString("state"))
        );
    }
}
```

I have tried to create `Bean` like this:

```java
@Bean
public UserUrlRepository getUserUrlRepository(MongoClient mongoClient, String dataBase, String collection){
    return new MongoUserUrlRepository(mongoClient, dataBase, collection);
}
```

But `mongoClient, dataBase, collection` is not recognized.

What am I missing?

Comment: Please add full class details where `getUserUrlRepository` method is present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first define a `MongoClient` bean and instruct the container where to find the 2 strings `dataBase` and `collection`
For the `String`s you can define them as property and use `@Value` annotation to inject them.

Edit code example:

```java
@Configuration
public class Config {

  @Bean 
  public MongoClient mongoClient(){ // This bean should exist, it will be used and injected in the getUserUrlRepository(..) method
      return new MongoClient();
  }

  @Bean
  public UserUrlRepository getUserUrlRepository(MongoClient mongoClient, @Value("${database.property}") String dataBase, @Value("${collection.property}") String collection){
      return new MongoUserUrlRepository(mongoClient, dataBase, collection);
  }
}
```

And sure, you should have defined `database.property` and `collection.property` in your application.properties or somewhere else.

Comment: Hi thank you for answer but can you please provide code example?

Comment: @user9347049 See my edit. Note that you could also defined the 2 strings as beans but it does not make sense to defined beans for primitive

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for